# Help optimizing and writing a global jQuery function

Tags: jquery, function, toggle, global

I am going to have a page with a list of 10 questions.

Each row is a question and each question has 4 radio buttons (horizontal unordered list using background images)

When I click a radio button in the first question, I clear all instances of the "checked" class and then add the "checked" class to the one I clicked. However, the buttons I click in question 1 cannot interfere with the buttons from question 2. So I am having a hard time to find a way to make this a global function that runs whenever I click ANY of the li items.

Here is my code:

**EDIT**: Added my code to jsfiddle.net - http://jsfiddle.net/bnA4g/3/ --Updated Link

```
li {
    list-style-type:none;
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.horiz {
    background:url(blankRadio.png) no-repeat center center;
    width:58px;
    height:58px;
}

.checked {
    background:url(checkedBtn.png) no-repeat center center;
    width:58px;
    height:58px;
}

$(function () {
    var row1 = $('div#row1 ul > li');
    var row2 = $('div#row2 ul > li');


        $("ul#row1Btns li").click(function () {
            $(row1).removeClass('checked');
            $(this).addClass('checked');
            console.log('checked');
        });

        $("ul#row2Btns li").click(function () {
            $(row2).removeClass('checked');
            $(this).addClass('checked');
            console.log('checked');
        });
});
```

Comment: post your html - or better still, make a working copy on jsfiddle.net and post the url

Comment: Ok let em add it to jfiddle...because for some reason the pre code tags in stack overflow won't show my HTML

Comment: Here is the link to it on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bnA4g/

Comment: You don't see anything because the entire thing is comprised of background images that aren't hosted anywhere? Can I add them to jsfiddle?

Comment: @Alex You should definitely post the basic html structure. Although we can glean info as to its structure based on your css and js, it would help to better understand your approach to the problem as a whole.

Comment: if the background images have a url accessible from internet - then just use that url and it will work

Comment: let me add the images to the web so I can link to em...one sec

Comment: Ok I updated teh jsfiddle with the images

Comment: Ok now it should be fully functioning on jsfiddle, sorry bout that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write:

```
$("div ul > li").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('checked');
    $(this).addClass('checked');
    console.log('checked');
});
```

this should do what you intended.

Comment: Instead of `.parent().children()`, why not just `.siblings()`? =)

Comment: you are right. didn't know that this function exists. .siblings() would be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a class to your rows and buttons, instead of addressing them by ID.  Then, remove the checked class from all rows, and then add it to the one that was just checked.

```
<ul class="buttons" id="row1btns">
    <li>...</li>
</ul>

<ul class="questions" id="row1">
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

And your script:

```
$("ul.buttons li").click(function () {
  $("ul.buttons li").removeClass('checked');
  $(this).addClass('checked');
  console.log('checked');
});
```

Also a style note, you've assigned your row1 variable as such:

```
var row1 = $('div#row1 ul > li');
```

It's not necessary to use the $ function with it again as you did here:

```
$(row1).removeClass('checked');
```

It's sufficient to use

```
row1.removeClass('checked');
```